# Error en el momento de usar OR en JPQL

Tags: java, sql, postgresql, jpa, glassfish

solicito de su colaboración para que me ayuden con una consulta que estoy haciendo y me retorna error. Lo he intentado con `createNativeQuery` y con `createQuery`, pero me está generando error; la idea es que recibe un parámetro y que pueda hacer la búsqueda en las columnas, ésta es la consulta que estoy ejecutando:

```
Query query = em.createNativeQuery(“ SELECT p” + “ FROM Profesor p” +
                                   “ WHERE lower(p.nombre) like :nombre”  +
                                   “ OR lower(p.apellido) like :apellido” +
                                   “ OR lower(p.genero) like :genero” +
                                   “ OR lower(p.estadoCivil) like :estado” +
                                   “ OR lower(p.emailPersonal) like :emailp” +
                                   “ OR lower(p.emailInstitucional) like :emaili” +
                                   “ OR lower(p.direccion) like :direccion”)
                                   .setParameter(“nombre”, “%”+ param.toUpperCase() + “%”)
                                   .setParameter(“apellido”, “%”+ param.toUpperCase() + “%”)
                                   .setParameter(“genero”, “%”+ param.toUpperCase() + “%”)
                                   .setParameter(“estado”, “%”+ param.toUpperCase() + “%”)
                                   .setParameter(“emailp”, “%”+ param.toUpperCase() + “%”)
                                   .setParameter(“emaili”, “%”+ param.toUpperCase() + “%”)
                                   .setParameter(“direccion”, “%”+ param.toUpperCase() + “%”);
```

y con:

```
Query query = em.createQuery("SELECT p FROM Profesor p WHERE " +
             "UPPER(p.nombre) like :parametro");
      query.setParameter("parametro", "%"+ param.toUpperCase() + "%")
           .setParameter("parametro", "%"+ param.toUpperCase() + "%");
```

el error que genera GlassFish es:

```
javax.persistence.PersistenceException: Exception [EclipseLink-4002]   (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.5.2.v20140319-9ad6abd): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException
Internal Exception: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: syntax error at or near “:”
Position: 57
Error Code: 0
Call: SELECT p FROM Profesor p WHERE lower(p.nombre) like :nombre OR lower(p.apellido) like :apellido OR lower(p.genero) like :genero OR lower(p.estadoCivil) like :estado OR lower(p.emailPersonal) like :emailp OR lower(p.emailInstitucional) like :emaili OR lower(p.direccion) like :direccion
Query: DataReadQuery(sql=” SELECT p FROM Profesor p WHERE lower(p.nombre) like :nombre OR lower(p.apellido) like :apellido OR lower(p.genero) like :genero OR lower(p.estadoCivil) like :estado OR lower(p.emailPersonal) like :emailp OR lower(p.emailInstitucional) like :emaili OR lower(p.direccion) like :direccion”)
```

Error generado

```
 javax.persistence.PersistenceException: Exception [EclipseLink-4002] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.5.2.v20140319-9ad6abd): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException
 Internal Exception: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: syntax error at or near ":"
 Position: 57
 Error Code: 0
 Call:  SELECT p   FROM Profesor p  WHERE lower(p.nombre) like :nombre     OR lower(p.apellido) like :apellido     OR lower(p.genero) like :genero     OR lower(p.estadoCivil) like :estado     OR lower(p.emailPersonal) like :emailp     OR lower(p.emailInstitucional) like :emaili     OR lower(p.direccion) like :direccion
 Query: DataReadQuery(sql=" SELECT p   FROM Profesor p  WHERE lower(p.nombre) like :nombre     OR lower(p.apellido) like :apellido     OR lower(p.genero) like :genero     OR lower(p.estadoCivil) like :estado     OR lower(p.emailPersonal) like :emailp)
```

Clase Profesor

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "profesor")
@XmlRootElement
@NamedQueries({
@NamedQuery(name = "Profesor.findAll", query = "SELECT p FROM Profesor p"),
@NamedQuery(name = "Profesor.findById", query = "SELECT p FROM Profesor p WHERE p.id = :id"),
@NamedQuery(name = "Profesor.findByIdProfesor", query = "SELECT p FROM Profesor p WHERE p.idProfesor = :idProfesor"),
@NamedQuery(name = "Profesor.findByTipoDocumento", query = "SELECT p FROM Profesor p WHERE p.tipoDocumento = :tipoDocumento"),
@NamedQuery(name = "Profesor.findByNumeroDocumento", query = "SELECT p FROM Profesor p WHERE p.numeroDocumento = :numeroDocumento"),
@NamedQuery(name = "Profesor.findByNombre", query = "SELECT p FROM Profesor p WHERE p.nombre = :nombre"),
@NamedQuery(name = "Profesor.findByApellido", query = "SELECT p FROM Profesor p WHERE p.apellido = :apellido"),
@NamedQuery(name = "Profesor.findByFechaDeExpedicion", query = "SELECT p FROM Profesor p WHERE p.fechaDeExpedicion = :fechaDeExpedicion"),
@NamedQuery(name = "Profesor.findByLugarDeExpedicion", query = "SELECT p FROM Profesor p WHERE p.lugarDeExpedicion = :lugarDeExpedicion"),
@NamedQuery(name = "Profesor.findByRh", query = "SELECT p FROM Profesor p WHERE p.rh = :rh"),
@NamedQuery(name = "Profesor.findByIdPaisNacionalidad", query = "SELECT p FROM Profesor p WHERE p.idPaisNacionalidad = :idPaisNacionalidad"),
@NamedQuery(name = "Profesor.findByGenero", query = "SELECT p FROM Profesor p WHERE p.genero = :genero"),
@NamedQuery(name = "Profesor.findByIdPaisLugarNacimiento", query = "SELECT p FROM Profesor p WHERE p.idPaisLugarNacimiento = :idPaisLugarNacimiento"),
@NamedQuery(name = "Profesor.findByFechaDeNacimiento", query = "SELECT p FROM Profesor p WHERE p.fechaDeNacimiento = :fechaDeNacimiento"),
@NamedQuery(name = "Profesor.findByIdPaisDeOrigen", query = "SELECT p FROM Profesor p WHERE p.idPaisDeOrigen = :idPaisDeOrigen"),
@NamedQuery(name = "Profesor.findByEstadoCivil", query = "SELECT p FROM Profesor p WHERE p.estadoCivil = :estadoCivil"),
@NamedQuery(name = "Profesor.findByIdDepartamento", query = "SELECT p FROM Profesor p WHERE p.idDepartamento = :idDepartamento"),
@NamedQuery(name = "Profesor.findByEmailPersonal", query = "SELECT p FROM Profesor p WHERE p.emailPersonal = :emailPersonal"),
@NamedQuery(name = "Profesor.findByEmailInstitucional", query = "SELECT p FROM Profesor p WHERE p.emailInstitucional = :emailInstitucional"),
@NamedQuery(name = "Profesor.findByTelefonoFijo", query = "SELECT p FROM Profesor p WHERE p.telefonoFijo = :telefonoFijo"),
@NamedQuery(name = "Profesor.findByCelular", query = "SELECT p FROM Profesor p WHERE p.celular = :celular"),
@NamedQuery(name = "Profesor.findByDireccion", query = "SELECT p FROM Profesor p WHERE p.direccion = :direccion"),
@NamedQuery(name = "Profesor.findByParams", query = " SELECT p" +
                                                            "   FROM Profesor p" +
                                                            "  WHERE lower(p.nombre) like :parametro" +
                                                            "     OR lower(p.apellido) like :parametro" +
                                                            "     OR lower(p.genero) like :parametro" +
                                                            "     OR lower(p.estadoCivil) like :parametro" +
                                                            "     OR lower(p.emailPersonal) like :parametro" +
                                                            "     OR lower(p.emailInstitucional) like :parametro" +
                                                            "     OR lower(p.direccion) like :parametro" )})
    public class Profesor implements Serializable {

        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
        @Basic(optional = false)
        @Column(name = "id")
        private Integer id;
        @Basic(optional = false)
        @NotNull
        @Column(name = "id_profesor")
        private int idProfesor;
        @Size(max = 2147483647)
        @Column(name = "tipo_documento")
        private String tipoDocumento;
        @Basic(optional = false)
        @NotNull
        @Column(name = "numero_documento")
        private BigInteger numeroDocumento;
        @Basic(optional = false)
        @NotNull
        @Size(min = 1, max = 2147483647)
        @Column(name = "nombre")
        private String nombre;
        @Basic(optional = false)
        @NotNull
        @Size(min = 1, max = 2147483647)
        @Column(name = "apellido")
        private String apellido;
        @Column(name = "fecha_de_expedicion")
        @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
        private Date fechaDeExpedicion;
        @Size(max = 2147483647)
        @Column(name = "lugar_de_expedicion")
        private String lugarDeExpedicion;
        @Size(max = 2147483647)
        @Column(name = "rh")
        private String rh;
        @Column(name = "id_pais_nacionalidad")
        private Integer idPaisNacionalidad;
        @Size(max = 2147483647)
        @Column(name = "genero")
        private String genero;
        @Column(name = "id_pais_lugar_nacimiento")
        private Integer idPaisLugarNacimiento;
        @Column(name = "fecha_de_nacimiento")
        @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
        private Date fechaDeNacimiento;
        @Column(name = "id_pais_de_origen")
        private Integer idPaisDeOrigen;
        @Size(max = 2147483647)
        @Column(name = "estado_civil")
        private String estadoCivil;
        @Column(name = "id_departamento")
        private Integer idDepartamento;
        @Size(max = 2147483647)
        @Column(name = "email_personal")
        private String emailPersonal;
        @Basic(optional = false)
        @NotNull
        @Size(min = 1, max = 2147483647)
        @Column(name = "email_institucional")
        private String emailInstitucional;
        @Size(max = 2147483647)
        @Column(name = "telefono_fijo")
        private String telefonoFijo;
        @Column(name = "celular")
        private BigInteger celular;
        @Size(max = 2147483647)
        @Column(name = "direccion")
        private String direccion;

        public Profesor() {
        }

        public Profesor(Integer id) {
            this.id = id;
        }

        public Profesor(Integer id, int idProfesor, BigInteger numeroDocumento, String nombre, String apellido, String emailInstitucional) {
            this.id = id;
            this.idProfesor = idProfesor;
            this.numeroDocumento = numeroDocumento;
            this.nombre = nombre;
            this.apellido = apellido;
            this.emailInstitucional = emailInstitucional;
        }

        public Integer getId() {
            return id;
        }

        public void setId(Integer id) {
            this.id = id;
        }

        public int getIdProfesor() {
            return idProfesor;
        }

        public void setIdProfesor(int idProfesor) {
            this.idProfesor = idProfesor;
        }

        public String getTipoDocumento() {
            return tipoDocumento;
        }

        public void setTipoDocumento(String tipoDocumento) {
            this.tipoDocumento = tipoDocumento;
        }

        public BigInteger getNumeroDocumento() {
            return numeroDocumento;
        }

        public void setNumeroDocumento(BigInteger numeroDocumento) {
            this.numeroDocumento = numeroDocumento;
        }

        public String getNombre() {
            return nombre;
        }

        public void setNombre(String nombre) {
            this.nombre = nombre;
        }

        public String getApellido() {
            return apellido;
        }

        public void setApellido(String apellido) {
            this.apellido = apellido;
        }

        public Date getFechaDeExpedicion() {
            return fechaDeExpedicion;
        }

        public void setFechaDeExpedicion(Date fechaDeExpedicion) {
            this.fechaDeExpedicion = fechaDeExpedicion;
        }

        public String getLugarDeExpedicion() {
            return lugarDeExpedicion;
        }

        public void setLugarDeExpedicion(String lugarDeExpedicion) {
            this.lugarDeExpedicion = lugarDeExpedicion;
        }

        public String getRh() {
            return rh;
        }

        public void setRh(String rh) {
            this.rh = rh;
        }

        public Integer getIdPaisNacionalidad() {
            return idPaisNacionalidad;
        }

        public void setIdPaisNacionalidad(Integer idPaisNacionalidad) {
            this.idPaisNacionalidad = idPaisNacionalidad;
        }

        public String getGenero() {
            return genero;
        }

        public void setGenero(String genero) {
            this.genero = genero;
        }

        public Integer getIdPaisLugarNacimiento() {
            return idPaisLugarNacimiento;
        }

        public void setIdPaisLugarNacimiento(Integer idPaisLugarNacimiento) {
            this.idPaisLugarNacimiento = idPaisLugarNacimiento;
        }

        public Date getFechaDeNacimiento() {
            return fechaDeNacimiento;
        }

        public void setFechaDeNacimiento(Date fechaDeNacimiento) {
            this.fechaDeNacimiento = fechaDeNacimiento;
        }

        public Integer getIdPaisDeOrigen() {
            return idPaisDeOrigen;
        }

        public void setIdPaisDeOrigen(Integer idPaisDeOrigen) {
            this.idPaisDeOrigen = idPaisDeOrigen;
        }

        public String getEstadoCivil() {
            return estadoCivil;
        }

        public void setEstadoCivil(String estadoCivil) {
            this.estadoCivil = estadoCivil;
        }

        public Integer getIdDepartamento() {
            return idDepartamento;
        }

        public void setIdDepartamento(Integer idDepartamento) {
            this.idDepartamento = idDepartamento;
        }

        public String getEmailPersonal() {
            return emailPersonal;
        }

        public void setEmailPersonal(String emailPersonal) {
            this.emailPersonal = emailPersonal;
        }

        public String getEmailInstitucional() {
            return emailInstitucional;
        }

        public void setEmailInstitucional(String emailInstitucional) {
            this.emailInstitucional = emailInstitucional;
        }

        public String getTelefonoFijo() {
            return telefonoFijo;
        }

        public void setTelefonoFijo(String telefonoFijo) {
            this.telefonoFijo = telefonoFijo;
        }

        public BigInteger getCelular() {
            return celular;
        }

        public void setCelular(BigInteger celular) {
            this.celular = celular;
        }

        public String getDireccion() {
            return direccion;
        }

        public void setDireccion(String direccion) {
            this.direccion = direccion;
        }

        @Override
        public int hashCode() {
            int hash = 0;
            hash += (id != null ? id.hashCode() : 0);
            return hash;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean equals(Object object) {
            // TODO: Warning - this method won't work in the case the id fields are not set
            if (!(object instanceof Profesor)) {
                return false;
            }
            Profesor other = (Profesor) object;
            if ((this.id == null && other.id != null) || (this.id != null && !this.id.equals(other.id))) {
                return false;
            }
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "edu.poli.prap.gd.data.Profesor[ id=" + id + " ]";
        }

    }
```

perdon seria algo asi:

```
Query query = em.createQuery(" SELECT p" +
                             " FROM Profesor p" +
                             " WHERE UPPER(p.nombre) like ?nombre" +
                             " OR UPPER(p.apellido) like ?apellido" +
                             " OR UPPER(p.genero) like ?genero" +
                             " OR UPPER(p.estadoCivil) like ?estadoCivil" +
                             " OR UPPER(p.emailPersonal) like ?emailPersonal" +
                             " OR UPPER(p.emailInstitucional) like ?emailInstitucional" +
                             " OR UPPER(p.direccion) like ?direccion")
    query.setParameter(nombre, “%”+ param.toUpperCase() + “%”)
         .setParameter(apellido, “%”+ param.toUpperCase() + “%”)
         .setParameter(genero, “%”+ param.toUpperCase() + “%”)
         .setParameter(estadoCivil, “%”+ param.toUpperCase() + “%”)
         .setParameter(emailPersonal, “%”+ param.toUpperCase() + “%”)
         .setParameter(emailInstitucional, “%”+ param.toUpperCase() + “%”)
         .setParameter(direccion, “%”+ param.toUpperCase() + “%”);
```

Nueva Consulta

```
Query query = em.createQuery("SELECT p FROM Profesor p WHERE " +
                                 "UPPER(p.nombre) like ?1" + 
                                 "UPPER(p.genero) like ?2");
      query.setParameter(1, "%"+ param.toUpperCase() + "%").setParameter(2, "%"+ param.toUpperCase() + "%");
```

Nuevo Error:

```
 java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: An exception occurred while creating a query in EntityManager: 
 Exception Description: Syntax error parsing [SELECT p FROM Profesor p WHERE      UPPER(p.nombre) like ?1UPPER(p.genero) like ?2]. 
 [52, 59] The positional input parameter ''{0}'' cannot use non-Integer characters.
 [70, 77]  The expression is invalid, which means it does not follow the JPQL grammar.
```

Comment: JPA no permite usar parámetros nombrados en consultas nativas, por lo que es normal que falle con `em.createNativeQuery`. ¿Te da el mismo error tanto cuando intentas usar consultas JPA como cuando lo intentas con nativas o es distinto? ¿Puedes enseñarnos la clase `Profesor`, y si no has hecho el  mapeo con anotaciones, el xml para el mapeo de la clase `Profesor`?

Comment: @Pablo adjunto clase y error generado

Comment: Has añadido otra vez el error con la consulta nativa. Yo preguntaba por el error cuando usabas JPQL. No sé si no lo tienes claro, pero cuando se usa `em.createNativeQuery` tienes que usar SQL, no JPQL.

Comment: @Pablo, no se hacer lo que me estas mencionando debido a que no se como pasarle el parametro en un query nativo

Comment: 1. Como he dicho, las consultas nativas no admiten parámetros nombrados, sólo posicionales (hazlo como en el ejemplo de Fer Mirabelli, pero con tu consulta de `em.createNativeQuery`). Después de eso, probablemente te siga dando error, pero te de un error distinto. 2. Pon el error que te da cuando usas em.createQuery, como te comenté. No has puesto ese error, sino que has repetido el mismo error de antes.

Comment: Este es el ejemplo clásico cuando tu DAO se desvirtúa y se convierte en un monstruo de métodos.

Comment: @Pablo, perfecto compañero, mil gracias ya funciono...!!!

Answer (score 1):

¿Has Probado usar parametros posicionales ? Con el segundo ejemplo que muestras quedaria de esta forma :

```
  Query query = em.createQuery("SELECT p FROM Profesor p WHERE " +
         "UPPER(p.nombre) like ?1");
  query.setParameter(1, "%"+ param.toUpperCase() + "%");
```

Saludos

Comment: la version de postgresql es la 9.5, no señor no funciono.

Comment: No funcionó, pero ¿Sigue con el mismo mensaje de error o cambió ?

Comment: mil gracias ya me funciono

Comment: @Gdaimon: [¿Qué debo hacer cuando alguien contesta mi pregunta?](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)